# Compare local and remote files using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, except, winscp-net

I'm trying to implement some logic to compare file information between remote server and local server.
I need to compare the file name between local folder and remote folder and download only the new files.
I tried using loading files in a list and use `Except` function, it didn't work.
Appreciate your help.

Please find one of the scenario I tried.

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    const string remotePath = "/Test";
    const string localPath = @"C:\Local";
    const string ArchivePath = @"C:\Users\Local\Archive";

    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(ArchivePath);
    RemoteDirectoryInfo dir1 = session.ListDirectory(remotePath);

    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list2 =
        dir2.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    IEnumerable<RemoteFileInfo> list1 =
        session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(remotePath, "*.csv", EnumerationOptions.None);

    var firstNotSecond = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
}
```

Getting error like

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Except(IQueryable, IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

Answer (score 1):

You will have to compare just the filenames:

```
var firstNotSecond =
    list1.Select(_ => _.Name).Except(list2.Select(_ => _.Name)).ToList();
```

---

Though note that WinSCP .NET has this functionality built-in. There's [`Session.CompareDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_comparedirectories).

And if you actually want to synchronize the directories, there's [`Session.SynchronizeDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories). One method that will do everything for you.

```
session.SynchronizeDirectories(
    SynchronizationMode.Local, localPath, remotePath, false).Check()
```